# How to configure vee-validate with i18n in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I want custom localization (en,ar) in my vuetify project. This are my files. divided in 3 main files.

**Component.vue**

```
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate';
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver,
  },

<validation-observer
  ref="observer"
  v-slot="{ invalid }"
>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <validation-provider
      v-slot="{ errors }"
      name="Name"
      rules="required"
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="name"
        :counter="10"
        :error-messages="errors"
        label="Name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </validation-provider>
    <v-btn
      class="mr-4"
      type="submit"
      :disabled="invalid"
    >
      submit
    </v-btn>
  </form>
</validation-observer>
```

**localization.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { extend, localize } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', required);

// Install English and Arabic localizations.
localize({
  en: {
    messages: en.messages,
    names: {
      name: 'E-mail Address',
    },
    fields: {
      name: {
        required: 'is too short, you want to get hacked?',
      },
    },
  },
  ar: {
    messages: ar.messages,
    names: {
      name: 'البريد الاليكتروني',
    },
    fields: {
      name: {
        required: 'كلمة السر قصيرة جداً سيتم اختراقك',
      },
    },
  },
});
localize(ar);
```

**main.js**

```
import "./common/validations";
```

If i change localize(ar), it only shows english, is there something im missing? (Later ill be changing that localize with a button.

Comment: What does your `vee-validate.js` look like? Checkout this fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-basic-i18n-bszvu?from-embed=&file=/src/vee-validate.js:23-71

Comment: i did exactly like that codesandbox and didn't work. any idea why? @maxshuty

Comment: Can you post more of your code? What version of VeeValidate are you using?

Comment: vee validate 3.4. by the way, the validations are ok but i cant change the localization. Do you have another method? @maxshuty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention which version of vee-validate are you using. I assume it's `v3`.

As per the documentation, the root localization object must contain the keys of the language if you are going to install locales without activating them, so:

```js
// ⛔️ Doesn't work
localize(ar);

// ✅ installs locale but doesn't activate it
localize({ ar });

// ✅ installs and activates locale
localize('ar', ar);
```

Check for more [details here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/localization.html#using-the-default-i18n)